# Android unable to resolve host with HttpPost - java.net.UnknownHostException

Tags: android

In my app am parsing json with HttpPost like this

`

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpParams httpParameters = httpClient.getParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setTcpNoDelay(httpParameters, true);
 HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();

  String url="http://ashishva.comxa.com/getdata_shoplistl_f.php?route="+sroute+"&shop_type="+sshoptype;
 HttpPost httpGet = new HttpPost(url);
  HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);
   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new  InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()`
```

My manifest file is set correctly for internet access

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

I am getting the json   in my browser, but getting the results in my android phone and emulator SOMETIMES ONLY. Why is this happening so? Why getting sometimes and not getting later.

While am not getting any data , am getting the exception

```
"java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "ashishva.comxa.com": No address associated with hostname"
```

Comment: fire the query from browser. - android browser

Comment: Type URL in android emulator browser and see the results are coming or not... sometime the emulator will not connect to the internet

Comment: When you say "sometimes only", is it possible it works on your phone but not in the emulator? Or does it "sometimes work in the phone" and "sometimes work in the emulator"?

Comment: where do you run above code? in Activity or Service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually i found out the solution. This line

```
HttpPost httpGet = new HttpPost(url);
```

had to be replaced with HttpGet as

```
 HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
```

Answer (score 1):

The best one I have found is in android developer training below is the link

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html

Connect and Download Data

```
    // Given a URL, establishes an HttpUrlConnection and retrieves
    // the web page content as a InputStream, which it returns as a string.

    private String downloadUrl(String myurl) throws IOException {
        InputStream is = null;
        // Only display the first 500 characters of the retrieved
        // web page content.
        int len = 500;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(myurl);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            // Starts the query
            conn.connect();
            int response = conn.getResponseCode();
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "The response is: " + response);
            is = conn.getInputStream();

            // Convert the InputStream into a string
            String contentAsString = readIt(is, len);
            return contentAsString;

        // Makes sure that the InputStream is closed after the app is
        // finished using it.
        } finally {
            if (is != null) {
                is.close();
            } 
        }
    }
```

Convert the InputStream to a String

```
    // Reads an InputStream and converts it to a String.
    public String readIt(InputStream stream, int len) throws IOException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        Reader reader = null;
        reader = new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8");        
        char[] buffer = new char[len];
        reader.read(buffer);
        return new String(buffer);

}
```